# Data frame string matching from one to another and replace with original value

Tags: python, dataframe, matching

i have two data frame , A and B . In A Data frame two column value and filed . and in B data frame  have also value and filed column.
i want to **match the  'value' column of B to A of'Filed' column**, **replace the Filed of A to  value of B**.

A=

```
 Value                     Filed        

valid username            username
valid username           input_txtuserid
valid username           name
Password                 input_txtpassword
Password                 txtPassword
Login                     input_submit_log_in
Login                     loginid
LOG IN                    SIGNIN
```

B=

```
 Value                     Filed        

input_txtuserid           "JOHN"
input_txtpassword          "78945"
input_submit_log_in        "Sucessfully"
City                       "London"
PLACE                      "4-A avenue Street"
PHONE                      789456
```

I want my data frame to look like this:

C=

```
 Value                     Filed        

valid username            "JOHN"
Password                   "78945"
Login                       "Sucessfully"
City                       "London"
PLACE                      "4-A avenue Street"
PHONE                      789456
```

Comment: Have you tried something out? Can you post your code and eventual errors?

Comment: i did not get any clue to start , if you have anything do let me know

Comment: With `B.set_index('Value')['Filed']`, you have a Series for `File` with `Value` as the index, and this thing can be treated as your mapping from `Value` to `File`. Then you can use it with `A['File'].map(...)` to apply your mapping on `A['File']`. See what you will get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a custom function to embed the logic and then apply it to the DataFrame by row.

```
import pandas as pd

A = pd.DataFrame({
    'Value':['valid username','valid username','valid username'],
    'Filed':['username', 'input_txtuserid', 'name']
})

B = pd.DataFrame({
    'Value':['input_txtuserid'],
    'Filed':['JOHN']
})


#dictionary mapping A.Filed and A.Value
_map = dict(zip(A.Filed.values, A.Value.values))



#Function embedding the logic
#It uses _map to determine the correct "filed" string
def get_correct_value(row, _map=_map):
    new_value = _map[row.Value]
    filed = row.Filed
    return new_value, filed



#Make a new df from the result of B.apply(function)
C = B.apply(get_correct_value, axis=1, result_type='expand')
C.columns = ['Value','Filed']
print(C)

#            Value Filed
#0  valid username  JOHN
```